# Java SWT TreeViewer get Selection Event when Selection has not changed but the user clicked it again

Tags: java, onclick, swt, selection, treeviewer

I have a `TreeViewer` with my own `Objects` and I added an `ISelectionChangedListener` but now I want to recognize if a user selects the same `Object` in the tree again.

Here is my `ISelectionChangedListener`:

```
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event)
            {
                if(event.getSelection() instanceof IStructuredSelection)
                {
                    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
                    UATreeNode treeNode = (UATreeNode) selection.getFirstElement();
                    NodeId currentUANodeId = treeNode.getNodeId();
                    if(!(treeNode.getAlreadyBrowsed() == true && treeNode.getNodeClass().equals(NodeClass.Object)))
                    {
                        treeNode.setAlreadyBrowsed(true);
                        treeNode.removeAll();
                        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                            browseNodes(currentUANodeId, treeNode);
                        });
                    }
                    else if(treeNode.getNodeClass().equals(NodeClass.Variable))
                    {
                        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                            getAndDisplayAttributesAndPropertiesFromNodeId(currentUANodeId, treeNode, true);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

`UaTreeNode` is the `Object` which my `ViewContentProvider` works. How can i detect now if the user selects the same Node again ?

Comment: Testing here the selection event fires again when you click on the same node a second time.

Comment: Ok sorry, that was my fault. Should have checked that first. 
With the onclick I want to update the information that is shown in the PropertiesView, but the values do not change.